# How to fix Xcode / simulator warnings: 'thirdPartyKeyboards' is already registered'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, warnings, simulator

I am implementing user-signup via simulator in Xcode and when I BEGIN typing text into SwiftUI TextFields (3 of them) the following 3 warnings occur when I click on each text-field.

I am typing text with my laptop's keyboard instead of using the simulator's keyboard.

How do you fix these warnings?

Thank you!

```
2021-02-07 07:25:39.403436-0600 AppProject[#####:#######] [KBDAnalyticsLog]
 -[TIAnalyticsService _registerEventSpec:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke
 TIAnalyticsEventSpec with name 'thirdPartyKeyboards' is already registered.

2021-02-07 07:25:42.529883-0600 AppProject[#####:#######] [KBDAnalyticsLog]
 -[TIAnalyticsService _registerEventSpec:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke 
TIAnalyticsEventSpec with name 'thirdPartyKeyboards' is already registered.

2021-02-07 07:25:42.542301-0600 AppProject[#####:#######] [KBDAnalyticsLog] -
[TIAnalyticsService _registerEventSpec:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke 
TIAnalyticsEventSpec with name 'thirdPartyKeyboards' is already registered.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue in my project. A couple of solutions I've found so far is to run the xc.workstation, make sure your pods are installed properly and check your Firebase settings. I'm rather new to Swift, I didn't manage to run this xc.workstation unfortunately.
If you already have any working solution to this issue, I'd highly appreciate!

Comment: Will keep you updated, I am not using Firebase though, created a Node API.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by setting "AutoFill Credential Provider" to YES in the app entitlements file.

[image]